# C array of structure gives random segfault + valgrind invalid write error

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc, valgrind

I have a random segfault in my code when I try to browse my structure array.

I have a struct_fd which contains the value of a socket, its type, 2 buffers and 2 pointers to function.
I also have my main server "env" structure (struct s_sv_prop) that contains a pointer to an array of struct_fd.

Header :

```
#define MAX_CLIENTS     10
#define MAX_SOCKETS     1 + MAX_CLIENTS
#define SK_SERV         0
#define SK_CLIENT       1
#define SK_FREE         2

typedef struct s_fd         t_fd;
typedef struct s_sv_prop     t_sv_prop;

struct          s_fd
{
    void    (*ft_read)();
    void    (*ft_write)();
    int     sock;
    int     type;
    char     rd[BUF_SIZE + 1];
    char    wr[BUF_SIZE + 1];
};

struct          s_sv_prop
{
    t_cmd           *cmd;
    t_fd            *fds;
    fd_set          readfds;
    fd_set          writefds;
    int             max;
    int             left;
    int             port;
};
```

Function where I allocate memory for my array of structure :

```
void                init_sv_prop(t_sv_prop *sv, char *port, char **env)
{
    int             i;

    i = 0;
    sv->max = 0;
    sv->left = 0;
    check_port(port);
    sv->port = (unsigned short) atoi(port);
    sv->cmd = (t_cmd *)malloc(sizeof(*(sv->cmd)));
    init_env(sv, env); /* initiate other env */
    init_command_list(sv); /* malloc an array of another struc */
    sv->fds = (t_fd *)malloc(sizeof(*(sv->fds)) * MAX_SOCKETS);
    while (i < MAX_SOCKETS) {
        clean_fd(&(sv->fds[i]));
        i++;
    }
}
```

I use clean_fd to clean all possible memory issue right after the malloc:

```
void        clean_fd(t_fd *fd)
{
    fd->type = SK_FREE; /* Valgrind : Invalid write of size 4 */
    fd->sock = 0;
    bzero(fd->rd, BUF_SIZE + 1);
    bzero(fd->wr, BUF_SIZE + 1);
    fd->ft_read = NULL;
    fd->ft_write = NULL;
}
```

Enventually when I want to display the state of my structure I randomly have a EXC_BAD_ACCESS segfault (not every time though...) :

```
void            sv_socket_state(t_sv_prop *sv, char *tag)
{
    int     i;
    char    *str;
    char    skfr[] = "FREE";
    char    sksv[] = "SERVER";
    char    skcl[] = "CLIENT";

    i = 0;
    while (i < MAX_SOCKETS)
    {
        if (sv->fds[i].type == SK_SERV)
            str = sksv;
        else if (sv->fds[i].type == SK_CLIENT)
            str = skcl;
        else
            str = skfr;
        printf("%5d | %6s | %5d | %6c | %6c\n", i, str, CL_SOCK(i),
            (FD_ISSET(CL_SOCK(i), &sv->readfds) ? 'X' : ' '),
            (FD_ISSET(CL_SOCK(i), &sv->writefds) ? 'X' : ' '));
        i++;
    }
}
```

When I run my code on OsX, as said previously, I randomly have a segfault when running the last function.
When I run it on Ubuntu, I got a malloc error and valgrind detects an invalid write error.

I must miss something the my allocations.
Do you have an idea of where the problem comes from ?

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: I deleted the cast, still get the issue.

Comment: @OP no no, that is not the asnwer, just a suggestion. You mind showing us the `t_fd` structure?

Comment: I've edited to add "define" in the header.
I'v omitted the other structures part of t_sv_prop that are also initiated using malloc for clarity but I can add them if required.

Comment: `sizeof(*(sv->fds)) * MAX_SOCKETS` => `sizeof(*(sv->fds)) * 1 + MAX_CLIENTS` : So need parentheses.

Comment: You might like to read about the pre-processor in general and how `#define`s are handled in particular. `#define`s are not variables!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : Ahh thanks... My macro caused an obvious error in malloc size... I'll be more carefull with macro next time.

Alk do you know a good solution on how to define MAX_SOCKETS accourding to MAX_CLIENTS all over the code ?
Thanks all for your help

Comment: `#define` are ok for this. Just use them appropriate .. ;-)

Comment: regarding this line: (and one other of a similar nature) 'sv->cmd = (t_cmd *)malloc(sizeof(*(sv->cmd)));'  'sizeof' is a compile time entry, not a run time entry.   There is no way for the sizeof( *sv->cmd) to know the number of bytes, at compile time, for the memory pointed to by sv->cmd at run time

Comment: To assure the malloc operation was successful, always check (!=NULL) the returned value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) said in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046387/c-array-of-structure-gives-random-segfault-valgrind-invalid-right-error#comment50115843_31046387),
the line :

```
sv->fds = (t_fd *)malloc(sizeof(*(sv->fds)) * MAX_SOCKETS);
```

is in fact:

```
sv->fds = (t_fd *)malloc(sizeof(*(sv->fds)) * 1 + MAX_CLIENTS);
```

and caused the malloc to be the size of *(sv->fds) + the value of MAX_CLIENTS.
The macro has to go from:

```
#define MAX_SOCKETS     1 + MAX_CLIENTS
```

to:

```
#define MAX_SOCKETS     (1 + MAX_CLIENTS)
```

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: As stated else where, in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc